# Как подключить библиотеку SFML в VS Code на линуксе?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, sfml, library

Как подключить библиотеку SFML в VS Code на линуксе ?

Answer (score -1):

Кароче

`sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Window", sf::Style::Close);

    sf::Event event;

    while(window.isOpen()){
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){

        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

`g++ main.cpp -o main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window`